# Bash if value on site changes then do

Tags: bash, sed, grep, wget, osx-elcapitan

i need to create a bash script that checks the following attribute from this site

http://blockchain.info/address/1TSTFc6NmGm81TQimXPFEEiXo9troR6Bv

```
Final Balance 0 BTC

<td id="final_balance"><font color="green"><span data-c="0">0 BTC</span></font></td>
```

what i want is to monitor the webpage to see if that 0 value changes and if so to echo that value in terminal and save it to a variable for later use.

im not great at bash but i know some things, iv been experimenting with the command below although i know my sed syntax is off and im not sure im doing it correctly.

its implemented as part of an applescript:-

```
set OUT to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/wget -q https://blockchain.info/address/1TSTFc6NmGm81TQimXPFEEiXo9troR6Bv -O - | sed -n 's/<td\\ id=\"final_balance\"><font color=\"green\"><span\\ data-c=\"[0-9]*\">[0-9]*\\ BTC</span></font></td>'"
```

any help fixing it would be greatly appreciated and i am more than happy to completely take a different approach as long as its easy to implement as a bash script or can be used in applescript.

im currently writing this script for the OSX platform.

many thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: Use their API - if you use this approach when they change the design of the page, your script will break.

Comment: that is a very valid point. that said, how would you approach this from using this method as i may use this method in other applications also. As a short term solution i could write a script to improve workflow of a single session even if i need to edit the script next time i want to use it.

Comment: Read the API documentation until you find the command that does what you want to do, then work from there.  You should be able to do it with a bash script, with either wget or curl.

Answer (score 0):

AppleScript has the `text item delimiters` value, which allows you to split up a string using the `text item` object. (Be careful to change it back when you're done, because subsequently using the `as string` cast on a list will insert the current text item delimiter between list items; and the value persists across the current AppleScript application, including all windows open in Script Editor, so it can lead to unexpected results. The default delimiter is an empty string.)

So, using that, you can do:

```
set OUT to do shell script "curl -s https://blockchain.info/address/1TSTFc6NmGm81TQimXPFEEiXo9troR6Bv"

set origDelim to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "Final Balance"
set theLine to paragraph 2 of text item 2 of OUT
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " BTC"
set theValue to last word of text item 1 of theLine
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to origDelim
```

`theValue` now contains the number you're looking for.

Or, if you prefer, here's a Bash solution that uses a similar approach, except that the delimiter in the "cut" command only can only take a single character, so we have to use a couple of them:

```
curl -s https://blockchain.info/address/1TSTFc6NmGm81TQimXPFEEiXo9troR6Bv \
| grep -A1 "Final Balance" | tail -n 1 | cut -d '>' -f 4 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

`grep -A1` grabs both the matching line and the one after it; `tail -n -1` discards the first of the two lines; then the two cuts isolate the value.

Note that I used curl because it's installed on all OS X systems by default whereas wget isn't, but you could use either, of course.